# Cannot deserialize Image after sending it through the network

Tags: c#, image, deserialization

So, I have these two methods, which I am using to serialize and deserialize Images:

```
private static Image GetImageFromString(string image)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image)))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(stream);
            }
        }

private static string GetImageAsString(Image image)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer());
            }
        }
```

If I do something Like this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var image = Image.FromFile(@"F:\phpide.png");

            pictureBox1.Image = image;

            var serialized = GetImageAsString(image);

            var secondImage = GetImageFromString(serialized);

            pictureBox2.Image = secondImage;
        }
```

It works as expected

Although, If I do something like this:

```
//client
    public void GetImage(JObject o)
            {
                var imageFile = o["file"].ToString();

                if (!File.Exists(imageFile))
                {
                    SendMessage("File does not exist");
                    return;
                }

                using (var image = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
                {
                    var serialized = GetImageAsString(image);

                    var ob = new JObject
                        {
                            { COMMAND, (int) Command.GetImage },
                            { "content", serialized }
                        };

                    Send(ob);

                    ob = null;

                    serialized = null;
                }
            }

//server
    public void ReceiveImage(JObject o)
            {
                var content = o["content"].ToString();

                var image = GetImageFromString(content);

                var form = new ImagePreviewForm(image);

                form.Show();
            }

//server

    public ImagePreviewForm(Image image)
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                pictureBox1.Image = image;
            }
```

The image is just blank.

I have checked and the image is being received correctly, with no data loss.

What could be going wrong here? Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least one problem:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer());
```

You shouldn't use `MemoryStream.GetBuffer` here - you should use `ToArray`. The `GetBuffer` method returns the underlying buffer *as-is*... complete with junk data at the end of the buffer, beyond the logical current length of the stream.

Additionally, you shouldn't close the stream when you call [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx). From the docs:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

So get rid of the `using` statement in `GetImageFromString`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `using` statement you are disposing the image before the UI thread can display the image properly.  Take the code out of the `using` block and add a `Dispose()` statement to the Form.Close() method.